# Recovering Windows 2003 Password - None of the tools work

Tags: windows-server-2003, passwords, password-recovery

I am trying to recover the password of Windows 2003 using the following tools and none of them works.

Existing environment setup:

1. Host PC runs Windows XP (it is kind of irrelevant here, but still...)
2. Microsoft Virtual PC 2007
3. Guest OS - Windows 2003

I have forgotten the administrator password (that is the only account defined) of the Windows 2003 which runs on Virtual PC.

I tried the following -

[Offline NT Password & Registry](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)

1. Downloaded the zip file.
2. Extracted the ISO image.
3. In Virtual PC, Captured this ISO image.
4. Initial screen came as below.
   [image]
5. I pressed Enter.
6. And, then it failed with the following error message.
   [image]

Why would it fail. I am not able to decipher as to why it fails. The error code does not make sense.

With whichever option I try in the initial screen, it always fails.

1. boot nousb
2. boot irqpoll
3. boot nodrivers

In addition to this tool, I tried [EBCD](http://www.prime-expert.com/ebcd/getting_started.php)

1. Downloaded the zip file.
2. Extracted the ISO image.
3. In Virtual PC, Captured this ISO image.
4. Initial screen came as below.[image]

And, then nothing happened. It was just blank screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**PS: I looked up these tools only through Superuser.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Microsoft Diagnostics and Recovery Toolset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff938845) to do the job? MSDaRT 6.0 supports Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks! But for this, I need to be logged into the server right? I am not even able to login to the Windows 2003 Server system as I have it configured for only account and that account's password is what I forgot!

Comment: @Kanini, no MSDaRT is a bootable CD.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! Will give it a try. Thanks!